# Mysql inserts data to mysql database everytime i reload page

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

I have done that when I push button it should insert data into mysql database but it only inserts it when I reload page.
Here Is the code:

```
<script>
function minuscredits()
{
    alert("hah");
    <?php
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits-1 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    ?>
}
</script>
```

When I push button I get alert but not insert into database only if I reload page it inserts successfully.

Comment: you can't mix php and javaScript like that

Comment: Mixing PHP and JS doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. It will run

```
<?php
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits-1 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
?>
```

when the page loads and only then.

To achieve what you want to do you need to make an ajax call.